# Cookies and Sessions. Is this a good practice?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm new to working with cookies, so forgive me for asking a naive question. I've heard that sessions are much for secure than cookies. So, while looking up examples, I found this:

```
// CREATE THEIR SESSIONS AND COOKIES
$_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
setcookie("id", $db_id, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
```

As you can see, the creator of this example is using session information within a cookie.

Is this the best approach for storing user data?

Is there any way to store data for a length of time in a session only?

Comment: If you save some sensitive information like password or your secret gf name (I'm not joking), then don't give it to the cookie,

Comment: @JanKaufmann Never save sensitive information like passwords.

Comment: You don't have to save session information in a standard cookie. You can change the session parameters with [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to make it not delete the cookie after the browser is closed.